# dc.js/crossfilter.js brushon filter - selected filtering not updating in other charts

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Filter/Brush ranges are not working for some values in one of my charts.

The range of this chart starts at 0 and ends at 300.

brush selection for Ranges > 100 are not working and the other charts are not filtering and displaying relevant data.

It would be helpful if someone can point out possible issue.

**Sample Data -  Begin**
ioi,analysis_date,closing_minutes,trade_time,window,price_channel,trade_quantity
No,02/28/2011,No,12:36.0,12:38:00,0.73,15,
No,02/28/2011,No,12:39.0,12:40:00,0.73,23,
No,02/28/2011,No,12:57.0,12:58:00,0.73,58,
No,02/25/2011,No,09:21.0,09:22:00,0.64,10,
No,02/25/2011,No,09:31.0,09:32:00,0.64,85,
Yes,11/30/2010,Yes,12:58.0,13:00:00,0.95,300,Long,
Yes,11/30/2010,Yes,12:58.0,13:00:00,0.95,200,Long,
**END**

**NO or YES is start of new line**

**CODE BEGIN**

```
    var analysis_date_dimension;
    var dimension_trade_qty;
    var dim_time_of_day;

    d3.csv("formatted_client_data.csv", function (error, response) {

        var min_trade_quantity = 0
        var max_trade_quantity = 310;

        response.forEach(function (d, i) {
            d.index = i;
            d.analysis_date = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse(d.analysis_date);
            d.trade_time = d3.time.format("%I:%M").parse(d.trade_time.split('.')[0]);
            d.date_time = getDateTime(d.analysis_date, d.trade_time);               
        });

        function getDateTime(date, time) {
            var dd = date.getDate();
            var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var yy = date.getFullYear();

            var hh = time.getHours();
            var ms = time.getMinutes();

            var x = yy + ',' + mm + ',' + dd + ' ' + hh + ':' + ms;

            return new Date(x);
        }

        var responseData = crossfilter(response);

        //Main Chart
        analysis_date_dimension = responseData.dimension(
                function (d) { return d.analysis_date; });

        var day_total = analysis_date_dimension.group().reduceSum(
                function (d) { return d.trade_quantity; });

        //Trade Quantity Chart
        dimension_trade_qty = responseData.dimension(
                function (d) { return d.trade_quantity; });

        var group_trade_qty = dimension_trade_qty.group().reduceCount(
                function (d) { return d.trade_quantity; });

        var day_chart = dc.barChart("#charts");
        var trad_qty_chart = dc.barChart("#chart_trade_qty");

        //Days chart
        day_chart
            .width(1024).height(340)
            .dimension(analysis_date_dimension)
            .group(day_total)
            .brushOn(true)               
            .x(d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(response, function (d) { return d.analysis_date; })))
            .yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format("d"));

        //Trade Quantity Chart
        trad_qty_chart
            .width(600).height(200)
            .dimension(dimension_trade_qty)
            .group(group_trade_qty)
            .brushOn(true)
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([min_trade_quantity,                 max_trade_quantity + 10]))
            .yAxis().ticks()
        ;
        dc.renderAll();
    });
```

**CODE END**

Comment: Can you create a working example? Say on JSFiddle or an alternative? It's not really clear to how the data is structured. I suspect you have dimensions that aren't naturally ordered, but very hard to tell if that's really the problem without a working example and access to real data.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. I figured it out. The data i had, had to be reformatted to number. d.trade_quantity = +d.trade_quantity; The brush filters are working as expected now.

Comment: Yup, that's usually a solution for the natural ordering issue. Glad you got it worked out. Cheers.

Comment: @user2651831 you should post that as an answer so this question won't be marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The data i had, had to be reformatted to number. d.trade_quantity = +d.trade_quantity; The brush filters are working as expected now.